# Postgres returns errors on future transactions

Tags: postgresql

I am currently migrating from MySQL to postgres using pgbouncer for my connection pool.

We select/insert/update/delete lots of data from postgres and all comes from remote sources so we try to make the data quality as good as possible before an insert but sometimes some bad data slips through.

This causes in postgres to report `current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block`

This is fine except that connection through pgbouncer will report this error for every query. I get the same logic if i connect directly to postgres instead of pgbouncer too. I'd expect it to roll back whichever transaction that caused this issue.

Is there a way to just rollback and continue working like normal? Everything i've read just says fix the query but in this case it's not always possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [`ROLLBACK`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-rollback.html) command.  This will undo everything since the last `BEGIN TRANSACTION` or `START TRANSACTION`.  Note that transactions do not nest; if you've begun multiple transactions without committing, this will roll back the outermost transaction.

This will drop you into autocommit mode.  You may want to issue a new `BEGIN TRANSACTION` command to open a new transaction.

You should also be able to [`ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-rollback-to.html), if you have a savepoint from before the error.

(If at all possible, it is preferred to just fix the query, but depending on what you're doing, that may be prohibitively difficult.)